# Numbered tag \begin{align} math equation

Tags: equations, align, tag

First of all, my previous question was closed bcz it was considered as a duplicate.  But it is not.  I've checked for duplicate links and the link is irrelevant because it only discusses image numbering. So, i'll ask again for the same topic.

I want the numbered tag on `\begin{align}` based on the section.

So, for example if i have section `2.3` (2.3 means Chapter 2 and Section 3) my tag must be automatically `2.3.1, 2.3.2,`, and so on.

Can you help me? Thanks in advance

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\section{one}
\blindtext
\chapter{Two}
\section{one}
\blindtext
\section{two}
\blindtext
\section{three}
\begin{align}
c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

To be clear the result of my equation should be:

[View image](https://ibb.co/P4PN3DX)

Comment: Your earlier query *was* a duplicate, as is this renewed posting. The link you refer to is not irrelevant. Indeed, it contains answers which suggest running either `\counterwithin{equation}{section}` or (since you employ the `amsmath` package) `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`. Since your document uses the `book` document class, either method produces the desired formatting of equation numbers.

Comment: @Mico there's a reason i'm not using `begin{equation}`. Cz one of my formulas using symbol "\\" to enter. And some of them only tagged on the bottom. Not on the center, which `\begin{align}` is required.

Comment: So, if it's possible, i only want using `begin{align}` but the numbered automatically based on the section. Thanks. Hope you can help me

Comment: `equation` is both the name of a *counter* and the name of an *environment*. The `equation` *counter* is incremented by `equation`, `align`, `gather`, `multline` and quite a few more display-math environments. It's the counter's appearance that you need to modify.

Comment: @user516076 as mico says the same counter is used for equation and align so this is a duplicate.  Also you should only use `align` when there are multiple lines and you specify alignment between them with `&`. Use `equation` for single line equations or you will get incorrect vertical spacing.